# PHP form to send email from Website

Tags: php, html, forms, dreamweaver

This is my html form requesting feedback.

What would the corresponding PHP form be to place on my webserver to send the email? I am new at website design and have only learnt CSS+ HTML.

```
<table width="518" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td width="165"><form name="form1" method="post" action="">
              <label for="nameco">Name/Company</label>
            :
            </form></td>
            <td width="343"><input name="nameco" type="text" id="nameco" size="70"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><form name="form2" method="post" action="">
              <label for="area">Area you are located :</label>
            </form></td>
            <td><input name="area" type="text" id="area" size="70"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><form name="form3" method="post" action="">
              Products interested in :
            </form></td>
            <td><table width="198">
              <tr>
                <td width="190"><label>
                  <input type="radio" name="Product" value="awnings" id="Product_0">
                  Awnings</label></td>
                </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><label>
                  <input type="radio" name="Product" value="carport" id="Product_1">
                  Carport/Shadeport</label></td>
                </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><label>
                  <input type="radio" name="Product" value="patio" id="Product_2">
                  Patio</label></td>
                </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><label>
                  <input type="radio" name="Product" value="other" id="Product_5">
                  Other
                  <input type="text" name="other1" id="other1">
                  </label></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><form name="form4" method="post" action="">
              <label for="contactno">Contact Number :</label>
            </form></td>
            <td><input name="contactno" type="text" id="contactno" size="70"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><form name="form5" method="post" action="">
              <label for="email">Email Address :</label>
            </form></td>
            <td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="70"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><form name="form7" method="post" action="">
              <label for="Comments">Additional Comments :</label>
            </form></td>
            <td><input name="Comments" type="text" id="Comments" size="70"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><form name="form8" method="post" action="">
              <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit">
            </form></td>
            <td><form name="form9" method="post" action="">
              <input type="submit" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset Form">
            </form></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

This is from dreamweaver. And how do i let the form know to send via this PHP file?

Comment: It's worth noting that you don't actually have any usable forms in this HTML...

Comment: As David pointed out, why would you add a form to everything BUT the inputs?

Comment: I'd take a look at form2email, there's a free version and it's really versatile! You just create your form, and then add the form2email PHP file as the action, and enter your email address within the PHP file itself, and then upload it all to your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I can give you advise, don't use so many forms, just use one and set `action` in `send.php`.

`send.php` can look like this:

```
<?php
$to = "$_POST['email']";
$subject = "$_POST['subject']";
$message = "$_POST['message']";
$from = "your@email.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```